# rendering behavior of remote linked files and script

Tags: html, rendering

lets say in my webpage i have added images, files & scripts which are not on available locally with respect to websites physical path

e.g

```
<script src"http://libraryheaven.com/somescript.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.styles.com/plugs/mystyle.css"/>

<img src="http://www.google.com/logo.png">
```

When the browser will start rendering the response HTML, then it will sort-of resolve dependencies, meaning it will then make separate HTTP requests to fetch the files from their remote location, or will it send request to the web-server of website to provide these and the that web-server will fetch these files and respond them to client or is the web-server intelligent enough to fetch and send all the dependencies.. please explain i haven't read the theory of rendering so i don't how it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter URL in your web browser you tell browser to fetch whatever can be found at that particular URL. And in most cases it is HTML file or some server code which produces HTML on the fly.

When browser gets HTML it knows how to and tries to interpret it (that's it's primary task after all).

Now when interpreting HTML browser "meets" tags with `src` or `href` attributes it makes **separate** request per attribute to URL in attribute value. These URLs usually point to images, style sheets, javascript files. Browser fetches whatever it finds there and tries to interpret the downloaded resources as well (show image, apply style sheet, execute javascript).

So to answer your question:
Yes, browser will download all the resources by itself from URLs in afore-mentioned attributes
No, web server does not take care of any external references in a served/produced HTML
No, web server does not try to play smart here and does not try to give you more than you ask for.

So basically if you put something like this in HTML

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/logo.png" />
```

then you know that any browser interpreting this HTML will try to fetch image `logo.png` from google.